# How can I run cypress in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress

I am having a problem running cypress in Jenkins. I specify 'cypress run' in the Execute NodeJS script section of the script, but I get the error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'run''.

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'run'
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1195:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v19.6.1
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Check this link: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/jenkins-and-cypress-tutorial/
I think it may help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to load to your tests into Jenkins workspace.
simple Jenkinsfile for running tests (this step for checkout code from repository into Jenkins workspace:

```
dir('TESTS') {
git branch: 'main',
url: 'git@YOUR_REPO.git',
credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDS_ID'
})
```

after that you can trigger tests and Jenkins should operate the cypress

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    // this image provides everything needed to run Cypress
    docker {
      image 'cypress/browsers:node-18.14.1-chrome-110.0.5481.96-1-ff-109.0-edge-110.0.1587.41-1'
    }
  }

  stages {
    // first stage installs node dependencies and Cypress binary
    // npm ci - install dependecies for Jenkins
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
        sh 'npm ci'
        sh 'npm run cy:verify'
      }
    }

    // this stage runs end-to-end tests, and each agent uses the workspace
    // from the previous stage
    stage('cypress tests') {

      // simple command for triggering tests
      // NO_COLOR environment variable to 1 to strip an ANSI color code from the output, and then runs Cypress
      // if need you can provide all params that you need
      steps{
        dir('TESTS') {
            git branch: 'main',
            url: 'git@YOUR_REPO.git',
            credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDS_ID'
        }
        sh 'NO_COLOR=1 cd TESTS && npm run cypress run'
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

I used this code, but I have other errors 

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\Node02\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:48
    throw err
    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> Node.js v19.6.0
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\Node02\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:48
    throw err
    ^

FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like something missed in your setup for Jenkins.
Please add docker plugin for your Jenkins.